# Why is Rails throwing an error after adding dependent: :nullify to my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Category which has many products and a Product which belongs to a Category.  When I delete a Category I want to make the category_id attribute of Product empty or nil.

I tried to accomplish this by adding dependent: :nullify to my has_many method in my Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :name, :length => { in: 4..16 }

  has_many :products, dependent: :nullify
end
```

I now get this error when trying to destroy an object:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

and better_errors references my destroy method as the issue, but it was working fine before I added dependent: :nullify, Here is the method:

```
def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Category was successfully destroyed"
      redirect_to categories_path 
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not delete Category"
      redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

Before I added the dependent: :nullify option it deleted records fine.

Here is my schema for categories and products:

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",        null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                                null: false
    t.string   "sku",                                 null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2, null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "products", ["name"], name: "index_products_on_name", using: :btree
  add_index "products", ["sku"], name: "index_products_on_sku", unique: true, using: :tree
```

Products does not forbid category_id from being null, so I don't think that is the problem.

Here is my product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

In my categories/show.html.erb I use the  name method like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1><%= @category.name %></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my categories/index.html.erb I use the name method once as well:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <h2><%= category.name %></h2>
      <p><%= category.description %></p>
      <p><%= link_to "Show", category_path(category.id) %>, <%= link_to "Edit", edit_category_path(category.id) %>, <%= link_to "Delete", category_path(category.id), method: "delete", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}  %></p>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

In both of those view I should never be using a nil category right? I don't think this is what the error is referencing since I get the same error in the console as well where views don't come into play.

I'm  not sure what the issue could be..Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the problem by updating rails to version 4.2.6 in my Gemfile.  It was previously version 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

**When you use nullify:**

it will set category_id to null and the place where you call product.category.name there can arise such type of error, `Undefined method name for nil:Class`. This is because there is no category for product and product.category returns nil. So, you needs to modify your code accordingly.

**Hope it helps**

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not calling product.category.name anywhere, and I get the same error when I try to destroy an object in my console so I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with me calling product.category.name any where in my display code.

Comment: Add your view where you have used name attribute.

Comment: I added the views where I call name on category